# Custom post type archive page thinks I'm not logged in

Tags: archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have created some custom post types using the Types plugin, and created their archive pages by copying my theme's archive.php and renaming it archive-{post type slug}.php.

When I view these archive pages while I am logged in (as the site administrator) the WordPress toolbar (admin bar) disappears and WordPress thinks I'm not logged in. The archives themselves work fine, displaying the toolbar as expected (as do all other pages).

Any ideas why custom post type archives would think a user is not logged in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening. Same thing was occurring with me. I ended up just adding the query (to pull the list of custom posts) to a page template. For some reason, that worked.